# Аренда инструментов или аренда инструмента?

Tags: грамотная-речь, единственное-множественное-число

Как правильно: аренда инструментОВ или аренда инструментА?
Или возможны оба варианта?

Answer (score 3):

Короче, возможны два варианта. 
Разница межде ними не очень значима, но если копнуть, то: 
аренда инструментов - если речь идет о конкретном списке; 
аренда инструмента - если речь идет об инструменте (инструментах) вообще, инстремент - используется как собирательное, хотя тут возможен и первый вариант: "инструментов".

> Аренда инструментов: леса строительные, перфоратор, гидропресс, триммер. А еще есть ремонт инструментов: там бензопилы, перфораторы, бетоносмесители и т.д.

Здесь, конечно, лучше "инструментов", поскольку есть конкретный список. 
Если такого списка, то можно и "инструмента".

Answer (score 2):

Если арендуют инструмент, то аренда инструмента. А если инструменты - инструментов.

Путаница скорей всего из-за того, что инструмент может быть обобщающим не только во множественном числе и в инструмент плотника будет входить не только топор, но в целом, да, зависит от числа.

Answer (score 1):

Было бы проще ответить, если б знать какого рода инструменты имеются в виду и в каком контексте.

Например, если речь идет о плотницком инструменте, то, пожалуй, здесь инструмент - обобщающее слово, даже если перечисляются разные наименования. Тогда "аренда инструмента".

Если речь о музыкальных инструментах, то тогда "аренда инструментов", поскольку здесь инструмент - это конкретное изделие. Его берут в аренду поштучно.

Comment: аренда инструментов: леса строительные, перфоратор, гидропресс,триммер. А еще есть ремонт инструментов: там бензопилы, перфораторы, бетоносмесители и т.д.

Comment: а вообще, насколько это серьезная ошибка?

Comment: "Наша фирма готова предложить в аренду строительный инструмент и оборудование. При необходимости высококлассные специалисты произведут ремонт ваших инструментов: бензопил, перфораторов, триммеров."

Гидропресс и бетоносмесители - это, пожалуй, уже оборудование, а не инструмент.